# Как победить ошибку «duplicate key value violates unique constraint» при UPDATE (PgSQL)?

Tags: golang

Хочу сказать, что в Go довольно таки недавно, большую часть ошибок, инфы конечно пытаюсь сам найти, но по данному вопросу к сожалению не смог найти решение и решил сюда написать.

Выполняется следующий запрос с помощью библиотеки **github.com/jackc/pgx/v4**:

```
var sql string = `
        UPDATE 
            web_pages 
        SET
            page_url = $2,
            meta_title = $3,
            meta_description = $4,
            meta_keywords = $5,
            page_h1 = $6,
            page_text = $7,
            index_status = true,
            updated_at = NOW()::timestamp
        WHERE
            id = $1
    `

res, err := dbn.Exec(ctx, sql, *id, details["url"], details["meta_title"], details["meta_description"], details["meta_keywords"], details["page_h1"], details["page_text"])
```

Где в результате получаю ошибку дубликата, хотя вроде я обновляю запись, а не добавляю (url одинаковый), отдельный запрос выполнил в Navicat все сработало успешно:

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "web_pages_page_url_unique" (SQLSTATE 23505)
```

Спасибо, буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: У Вас довольно интригующий вопрос... дело еще и в том, что в ошибке сказано, что "нарушается констрейн с именем web_pages_page_url_unique". А вот сам этот constrain у Вс в воопросе не приведен... А хотелось бы на него посмотреть. Ну, потому что это - объект базы данных, именованный, он выхывает ошибку при определенных дейстиях... может, Вы найдёте его по имени и добавите к вопросу?

Comment: `хотя вроде я обновляю запись, а не добавляю` - то что обновляете не имеет значения. Имеет значение, что в результате операции в таблице получаются две записи с одинаков значением в поле (очевидно `page_url`), на которое наложено ограничение уникальности.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA - я правильно понимаю, что это - такая особенность Postgres, которой нет, например, в MySQL или MS SQL?

Comment: @S.H. Нет. Так работает любая БД

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Спасибо большое, еще раз внимательнее перепроверил данные и действительно был дубликат, а это уже другой вопрос, буду разбираться в причинах теперь.

Comment: @S.H. этот ключ был сгенерирован ранее с помощью Laravel, вот сам constrain если интересно: `CONSTRAINT "web_pages_page_url_unique" UNIQUE ("page_url")`